# I want to transfer JComboBox info into this JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Am pressing the Button but it's not working for some reason.
I want to transfer `JComboBox` info into this `JTable`.

Here's what the GUI looks like

[image]

Please help me fix this issue. I am suspect it's a logic error.
I just want the contents in the dropbox to be transferred to the 2nd table (Which is basically empty)

Here's the code:

```
package com.mycompany.expoapp.newpackage;

import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ExpoAPP extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    DefaultTableModel model;

    /**
     * Creates new form ExpoAPP
     */
    public ExpoAPP() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                         
    private void initComponents() {
        Dropbox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        visit = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        notvisit = new javax.swing.JTable();
        VISITED = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Dropbox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select the Pavillion you Visited", "Algeria Pavillion", "Brazil Pavillion", "Chile Pavillion", "Denmark Pavillion", "Ethiopia Pavillion", "Fiji Pavillion", "Germany Pavillion", "Hungary Pavillion", "Indonesia Pavillion", "Japan Pavillion", "Korea Pavillion", "Luxembourg Pavillion", "Malaysia Pavillion", "Niger Pavillion", "Palestine Pavillion", "Qatar Pavillion", "Rawanda Pavillion", "Singapore Pavillion", "UK pavillion", "Venezuela Pavillion", "Yemen Pavillion", "Zambia Pavillion" }));
        Dropbox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DropboxActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        visit.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
            },
            new String [] {
                "Visited"
            }
        ));
        visit.setAlignmentX(1.0F);
        visit.setAlignmentY(1.0F);
        visit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                visitMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(visit);

        notvisit.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"Algeria Pavillion"},
                {"Brazil Pavillion"},
                {"Chile Pavillion"},
                {"Denmark Pavillion"},
                {"Ethiopia Pavillion"},
                {"Fiji Pavillion "},
                {"Germany Pavillion"},
                {"Hungary Pavillion"},
                {"Indonesia Pavillion"},
                {"Japan Pavillion"},
                {"Korea Pavillion"},
                {"Luxembourg Pavillion"},
                {"Malaysia Pavillion"},
                {"Niger Pavillion"},
                {"Palestine Pavillion"},
                {"Qatar Pavillion"},
                {"Rawanda Pavillion"},
                {"Singapore Pavillion"},
                {"UK pavillion"},
                {"Venezuela Pavillion"},
                {"Yemen Pavillion"},
                {"Zambia Pavillion"}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Not Visited"
            }
        ));
        notvisit.setAlignmentX(1.0F);
        notvisit.setAlignmentY(1.0F);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(notvisit);

        VISITED.setText("Visited!");
        VISITED.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                VISITEDActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Dropbox, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(132, 132, 132)
                .addComponent(VISITED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                .addComponent(Dropbox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 385, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(VISITED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void DropboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void visitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
int selectedRow = visit.getSelectedRow();
    String comboSub = model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0).toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < Dropbox.getItemCount(); i++) 
{
           if (Dropbox.getItemAt(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(comboSub)) 
               {
                Dropbox.setSelectedIndex(i);
               }
}
    }                                  

    private void VISITEDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    /*
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpoAPP.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpoAPP.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpoAPP.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpoAPP.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ExpoAPP().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> Dropbox;
    private javax.swing.JButton VISITED;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable notvisit;
    private javax.swing.JTable visit;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. It should take far less than 190 lines of code to get to .. failing to transfer data between a single combo box and a table. 2) Choose tags carefully. This was tagged applet and nothing else. A (Java) applet was nowhere involved, but Java, Swing, JTable & JCombobox *are* all relevant and available as tags.

Comment: I added an image of your GUI to your question.  You have a dropbox and a table with a list of pavilions.  Why do you need both?  You either have a dropbox or a table with a list of pavilions.  A table with a list of pavilions usually has buttons between the two tables to move items in both directions.  It appears that what you want are called bi-directional selection tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answering The Question

You're not learning Swing by using a GUI builder.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

You have a dropbox and a table with a list of pavilions. Why do you need both? You either have a dropbox or a table with a list of pavilions. A table with a list of pavilions usually has buttons between the two tables to move items in both directions. It appears that what you want are called bi-directional selection lists.

Also, you have two different lists of pavilions.  Fiji has an extra space in the table list and the UK pavilion has pavillion uncapitalized.

Here's the GUI after selecting three pavilions.

[image]

Modify these methods.

```
private void DropboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void visitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                  

private void VISITEDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Keep user from selecting "Select..."
    int index = Dropbox.getSelectedIndex();
    if (index <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Add visited pavilion
    String pavilion = ((String) Dropbox.getSelectedItem()).trim();
    Object[] modelRow = new Object[] { pavilion };
    DefaultTableModel visitModel = (DefaultTableModel) visit.getModel();
    visitModel.addRow(modelRow);

    // Remove visited pavilion
    Dropbox.removeItem(pavilion);
    Dropbox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    DefaultTableModel notvisitModel = (DefaultTableModel) notvisit.getModel();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector<Vector> vector = notvisitModel.getDataVector();
    int size = vector.size();
    for (index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        Vector<?> innerVector = vector.get(index);
        String visitedPavilion = ((String) innerVector.get(0)).trim();
        if (pavilion.equals(visitedPavilion)) {
            vector.remove(index);
            notvisit.repaint();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

## A Better Way

I created what I've seen as a bi-directional selection list.

I didn't use a GUI builder.  I coded the Swing GUI by hand.

Not only does the selection list work in both directions, but the sort order of the pavilions is also maintained.

Here's the GUI when starting the application.

[image]

Here's the GUI after selecting three pavilions.  You select multiple pavilions by holding down the Ctrl key while left-clicking the mouse on the pavilions you've visited.

[image]

Here's the GUI after left-clicking the `>` button.

[image]

Here's the GUI after I changed my mind snd removed one pavilion.

[image]

Here's the final state of the GUI.

[image]

## Explanation

I created one model for the not visited pavilions.  I don't have to worry about two data models holding inconsistent information.

I extended the `DefaultListModel` class to add a sort method.  This method ensures that the pavilion list in both the not visited and visited `JLists` will be in alphabetical order.

I coded a `JFrame`, a main `JPanel`, and two inner `JPanels`.  The `JFrame` uses a default `BorderLayout`.  The main `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` and holds the two inner `JPanels` and the two `JButtons`.

Each inner `JPanel` uses a `BoxLayout` and holds a `JLabel` and a `JList` inside of a `JScrollPane`.  I made both inner `JPanels` the same preferred size.

Here's the complete runnable code.  i made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ExpoGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ExpoGUI());
    }
    
    private final ExpoModel model;
    
    private JList<String> notVisitedList, visitedList;
    
    public ExpoGUI() {
        this.model = new ExpoModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Expo GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JPanel notVisitedPanel = createNotVisitedPanel();
        JPanel visitedPanel = createVisitedPanel();
        visitedPanel.setPreferredSize(notVisitedPanel.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(notVisitedPanel);
        
        JButton removeButton = new JButton("<");
        panel.add(removeButton);
        
        removeButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            int[] indices = visitedList.getSelectedIndices();
            String[] pavilions = new String[indices.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
                pavilions[index] = model.getVisitedListModel().get(indices[index]);
                model.addNotVisited(pavilions[index]);
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
                model.removeVisited(pavilions[index]);
            }
            model.getNotVisitedListModel().sort();
            model.getVisitedListModel().sort();
        });
        
        JButton addButton = new JButton(">");
        panel.add(addButton);
        
        addButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            int[] indices = notVisitedList.getSelectedIndices();
            String[] pavilions = new String[indices.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
                pavilions[index] = model.getNotVisitedListModel().get(indices[index]);
                model.addVisited(pavilions[index]);
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
                model.removeNotVisited(pavilions[index]);
            }
            model.getNotVisitedListModel().sort();
            model.getVisitedListModel().sort();
        });
        
        panel.add(visitedPanel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createNotVisitedPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Not Visited");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(label);
        
        notVisitedList = new JList<>(model.getNotVisitedListModel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(notVisitedList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createVisitedPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Visited");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(label);
        
        visitedList = new JList<>(model.getVisitedListModel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(visitedList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class ExpoModel {
        
        private final String [] pavilions = {            
            "Algeria Pavilion",
            "Brazil Pavillon",
            "Chile Pavilion",
            "Denmark Pavilion",
            "Ethiopia Pavllion",
            "Fiji Pavilion",
            "Germany Pavilion",
            "Hungary Pavilion",
            "Indonesia Pavilion",
            "Japan Pavilion",
            "Korea Pavilion",
            "Luxembourg Pavilion",
            "Malaysia Pavilion",
            "Niger Pavilion",
            "Palestine Pavilion",
            "Qatar Pavilion",
            "Rawanda Pavilion",
            "Singapore Pavilion",
            "UK Pavilion",
            "Venezuela Pavilion",
            "Yemen Pavilion",
            "Zambia Pavilion"
        };
        
        private final SortedListModel notVisitedListModel, visitedListModel;
        
        public ExpoModel() {
            this.notVisitedListModel = new SortedListModel();
            this.visitedListModel = new SortedListModel();
            
            for (int index = 0; index < pavilions.length; index++) {
                this.notVisitedListModel.addElement(pavilions[index]);
            }
        }
        
        public void addNotVisited(String pavilion) {
            notVisitedListModel.addElement(pavilion);
        }
        
        public void addVisited(String pavilion) {
            visitedListModel.addElement(pavilion);
        }
        
        public void removeNotVisited(String pavilion) {
            notVisitedListModel.removeElement(pavilion);
        }
        
        public void removeVisited(String pavilion) {
            visitedListModel.removeElement(pavilion);
        }

        public SortedListModel getNotVisitedListModel() {
            return notVisitedListModel;
        }

        public SortedListModel getVisitedListModel() {
            return visitedListModel;
        }
    
    }
    
    public class SortedListModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String[] array;

        public void sort() {
            if (getSize() <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            
            array = new String[getSize()];
            copyInto(array);
            Arrays.sort(array);
            clear();

            for (String s : array) {
                addElement(s);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! This Really Helped alot :)